# XAxis DateTime Format to show 12-Hour for Vaadin Charts?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-charts

I'm trying to format the date time labels for the XAxis on Vaadin Charts. It will show the 24-hour format by default but when I try to set it to show 12-hour format it only works when I have the window in half size.

[image]

[image]

The top shows the x-axis labels when the screen is in full screen. The bottom shows it when the window is in half screen.

Here is my code:

```
DataSeries dataSeries = new DataSeries();
    dataSeries.setName("Events");

    int eventCounter = 0;

    for (Event event : eventList) {
        eventCounter++;
        dataSeries.add(new DataSeriesItem(event.getDate(), eventCounter));
    }

    configuration.addSeries(dataSeries);

    DateTimeLabelFormats dateTimeLabel = new DateTimeLabelFormats();
    dateTimeLabel.setHour("%l:%M %p");

    configuration.getxAxis().setDateTimeLabelFormats(dateTimeLabel);
```

Comment: the code you posted,  is that for the fullscreen or halfscreen mode?  And how does it differ from other mode?

Comment: @petey Hey thanks for the response, It's no specific to either. What I mean by full screen is when the web page is full screen, it shows the time in 24-hour format. But lets say I make the window split-screen then the xAxis will format to 12-hour.

Comment: Appreciate if you could share the source code of the above vaadin chart with X Axis for 15 mins each node.